# The class the virtual method refers to, returns null ASP.Net Core MVC

Tags: c#, reference, virtual, nullreferenceexception

I am coming with question.

Why my class returns null value?

As You can see on [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IFow.png), class is returning null, but fields inside are [not null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIqvo.png).

This is Post model where I place virtual method to class Category, and the class [is null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKlAx.png)

Why is that happening?

I checked every reference, and it's all good.
This may be caused by Windows Update or IIS/VisualStudio?

Please help

**Post Model**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace collector_forum.Data.Models
{
    public class Post
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }

        public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

        public virtual Category Category { get; set; }

        public virtual IEnumerable<PostReply> Replies { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Category Model**:

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace collector_forum.Data.Models
{
    public class Category
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime Created { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }
        public virtual IEnumerable<Post> Posts { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Index** and **BuildHomeIndex** methods from HomeController:

```cs
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            var model = BuildHomeIndexModel();
            return View(model);
        }

        public HomeIndexModel BuildHomeIndexModel()
        {
            var latestPosts = _postService.GetLatestPosts(10);

            var posts = latestPosts.Select(post => new PostListingModel
            {
                Id = post.Id,
                Title = post.Title,
                AuthorId = post.User.Id,
                AuthorName = post.User.UserName,
                AuthorRating = post.User.Rating,
                DatePosted = post.Created.ToString(),
                RepliesCount = post.Replies.Count(),
                Category = GetCategoryListingForPost(post)
            });

            return new HomeIndexModel
            {
                LatestPosts = posts,
                SearchQuery = ""
            };
        }
```

**PostListingModel** if needed:

```cs
using collector_forum.Models.Category;

namespace collector_forum.Models.Post
{
    public class PostListingModel
    {
        public CategoryListingModel Category { get; set; }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public string AuthorName { get; set; }
        public int AuthorRating { get; set; }
        public string AuthorId { get; set; }

        public string DatePosted { get; set; }

        public int CategoryId { get; set; }
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
        public string CategoryImageUrl { get; set; }

        public int RepliesCount { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**CategoryListingModel** if needed too:

```cs
using collector_forum.Models.Post;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace collector_forum.Models.Category
{
    public class CategoryListingModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

        public int NumberOfPosts { get; set; }
        public int NumberOfUsers { get; set; }

        public bool HasRecentPost { get; set; }
        public PostListingModel Latest { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't post images of code, give us the actual code so we can copy/paste as required.

Comment: What is the problem. Have you got any error?

Comment: Sure, here you go - [error](https://imgur.com/BoRlYYL)